# Is it possible to add custom Components in the InspectorControls to the new "Styles" Tab?

Tags: block-editor

I successfully added new Components to the `wp.blockEditor.InspectorControls` with the `editor.BlockEdit` filter with `wp.compose.createHigherOrderComponent` which returns the extended Component like this:

```
<Fragment>
    <BlockEdit { ...props } />
    <InspectorControls>
        <MyComponent>
            ...
        </MyComponent>
    </InspectorControls>
</Fragment>
```

How could i extend this code to place MyComponent in the new Styles Tab in InspectorControls?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also looking for this answer and found it here:
https://make.wordpress.org/core/2023/03/07/introduction-of-block-inspector-tabs/

Basically you just have to add this: group="styles"

```
<wp.blockEditor.InspectorControls group="styles">
```